# "Would you prefer to walk rather than run?" vs "Would you prefer to walk or run"

Tags: grammar

I am a native speaker and I feel that I use both of these constructs.  Have I been mistaken all these years?  If not, what's the subtle difference between the 2.  Looking for other opinions.  My thoughts are.

"Would you prefer to walk or run" = Would you prefer to walk? OR Would you prefer to run?
Asking this as they are about to depart to somewhere.

"Would you prefer to walk rather than run?"
Someone saying they really don't want to run...so giving another suggestion before departing.

Comment: Those work for me. What prompted the question?

Comment: What are you asking? You already say there is a difference, which there is. The first example is a straight question. In the second example it has already been agreed or understood that they would run.

Comment: Was asking for others opinions to verify if I wasn't making a mistake.  Some English habits can be wrong. lol

Comment: Would you rather walk or run?

Comment: The intonation would signal any difference, and some others that aren't obvious in print.